# C how to free sub memory?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, free

I allocate a big memory , `char* test= malloc(10000000);` , then I put value on this memory , and do some work for each value.

What I want is , each 1000 index, I want to release all the memory until it.

For ex.

```
for(long i=0; i<10000000;i++)
   DoSomeWork(test[i]);
   if(i%1000==0)
       releaseMemory(i-1000,i);
```

How can I do it in c?

I know that `free` can only free all of my allocate, but I don't want to wait to the end of work the free all the memory.

I want each 1000 works free all the 1000 back

I must to allocate all the memory in the begining of program.

Comment: If you're allocating memory once up front, what do you think it even means to "free" it inside the loop? What is happening inside your DoSomeWork() function that you think you need to undo periodically?

Comment: You need to write your own memory allocator for what you want. Work in reverse order and call `brk()` and friends when needed.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do this. One is to continue allocating one large block at the system level, but use your own mechanism to control which of _your_ objects gets to use which bit of _your_ memory. For example, you might have an array of flags indicating which chunks of memory are in use at any given time. The other way is to break up your allocation into smaller pieces, freeing those (and potentially re-allocating them) when appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

What you want can be achieved by allocating the program in smaller chunks.

You have to adjust your algorithm to handle a bunch of small sub-arrays which you then can release after use.

In this case, it might be useful to allocate the chunks in reversed direction to give the libc the chance to release the freed memory to the underlying OS.

Let me enhance a bit here:

Assume you want an array with 10000000 (10 million) entries. Instead of allocating it as one chunk as depicted in the question, it could be possible to have

```
#define CHUNKSIZE 10000
#define ENTRYSIZE 8
#define NUM_CHUNKS 1000

void test(void)
{
    void** outer_array = malloc(NUM_CHUNKS * sizeof(void*))
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CHUNKS; i++) {
        void * chunk = malloc(CHUNKSIZE * ENTRYSIZE);
        outer_array[NUM_CHUNKS - 1 - i] = chunk;
        // allocate them in reverse order
    }

    // now, set item #123456
    size_t item_index = 123456;
    // TODO check if the index is below the maximum
    size_t chunk_index = item_index / CHUNKSIZE;
    size_t index_into_chunk = item_index % CHUNKSIZE;
    void * item_address = &outer_array[chunk_index][index_into_chunk * ENTRY_SIZE];

    // after having processed one chunk, you can free it:
    free(outer_array[0]);
    outer_array[0] = NULL;
}
```

There are (roughly) two possibilities how a program can enhance the heap in order to allocate memory:

1. It can obtain a completely new memory block from the OS, indepedent from the "main address space". Then it can use it for allocation and return it to the OS as soon as it is `free()`d. This happens in some allocators if the allocation size is above a certain threshold.
2. It can enhance the program address space. Then, the new memory is added at the end. After `free()`ing the last memory block, the program address space can be reduced again. This happens in some allocators if the allocation size is below a certain threshold.

This way, your program's memory footprint decreases over time.

Comment: one can also use `realloc` with a smaller size. Not sure it frees a lot, though

Comment: Also keep in mind that just because you `free` memory doesn't necessarily mean it will become available to the OS right away (or even soon).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I thought that too, but problem with `realloc` is that it frees from end, not start. And what he wants is from start.

Comment: you could compute the array in reverse by 1000 chunks. it's ugly, though, lots of adds & subs & index magic. eeek